# JQuery:Image cannot bind in image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am working with binding dynamic images in the image tag.My problem is Iam not be able to display the  image when name contains space.Here is the code:

```
             for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
                {
                                alert(names[i]);
                      <img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="Water lilies.jpg"></img>/////This code works if name  is given directly
                  imageTags='<img style="width:100px;height:100px" src=' +names[i]+ '></img>';
                 $("#images").append(imageTags);
                }
```

here Iam getting the two image names in the alert --"Sunset.jpg" and "Water lillies.jpg".
I can see the image sunset.jpg but not Water lillies.jpg.
In the console the image tag looks likes this:

```
          <img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="Water" lilies.jpg>
```

and got an error:"Failed to load resource "
But when I avoid the space between Water and lillies it works.How can i solve this problem??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case:

If an attribute value contains spaces, then it must be quoted. You have failed to include quote marks.

```
src="' + names[i] + '">
```

But building HTML by mashing strings together is error prone and hard to read. Don't do that:

```
var img = jQuery('<img>').
             attr('src', names[i]).
             css({ width: "100px", height: "100px" });
```

In this specific case:

URLs can't include (literal) spaces. Encode them.

```
var img = jQuery('<img>').
             attr('src', encodeURIComponent(names[i])).
             css({ width: "100px", height: "100px" });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       imageTags='<img style="width:100px;height:100px" src=' +names[i]+ '></img>'; // your code
       imageTags='<img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="' +names[i]+ '"></img>'; // change
```

hope this helps..